# Using QTDeuce in Overleaf

Tags: fonts, fontspec, overleaf

I would like to use the [QT Deuce font](https://tug.org/FontCatalogue/qtdeuce/) in overleaf. It is in the LaTeX font catalogue, but the instructions for usage on that site use the `fontspec` package which requires XeTeX or LuaTeX rather than the pdflatex that Overleaf uses. Is it possible to use QT fonts in overleaf?

Comment: To a first approximation: no. That is, you could, but you'd have to create (or persuade somebody else to create) a suitable package for pdfTeX and to convert the font files into a format the engine can use. pdfTeX can use truetype fonts, but not opentype (and there are some limitations on the way truetype can be used, though you can work around many of them). If you're asking this question, this is not something you probably want to do ;).

Comment: True, Overleaf uses `pdflatex` by default. However, it has never been restricted to it. After opening one of your project, you can open the menu at the top left and change to `xetex` or `luatex` in the compiler field.

Comment: @KersouMan Just wow <facepalm>. I've been using Overleaf on average for multiple hours a day for the past few years and I didn't know this (mostly because pdflatex has been sufficient for my real job, and this is for a hobby project). Thank you for the enlightenment.

Comment: @D.J.P. It happens, force of habit leads us to overlook certain functions in the tools we use